# document.querySelector returning null

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make my own version of jQuery. I am using this code so far, to test my selectors:

```
js(".hide");

function js(selector){
    var applyTo = document.querySelector(selector);
    applyTo.style.color = 'red';
}
```

However, this does not work, and the error console said: 
 `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`
Why is `applyTo` null?

Comment: Do you have any elements with the class `hide`? - If so, is this code running before the DOM is loaded?

Comment: I realize that what your doing is for learning purposes, as opposed to reinventing the wheel, but man, that's a big project.  Have you considered just taking an existing library and adding stuff to it?

Comment: @tymeJV, Thanks. It was running before the dom was loaded

Comment: @durbnpoisn, I am doing this for the challenge. So far it's been quite a big one :))

Comment: Note that [Document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) doesn't work in IE < 8 so you might want to use a [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/chrisjlee/8960575).

Answer (score -1):

To make it not fail in case the selector doesn't get you any element:

```
function js(selector){
    var applyTo = document.querySelector(selector);
    if(applyTo) { applyTo.style.color = 'red'; }
}
```

Make sure it's called only after the DOM has loaded.